# Regularization of the following sum

Tags: divergent-series

Am interested in how one could regularize the following sum 
$\sum_{m,n = 1, \infty} \sqrt{m^2 + n^2}$. Would preferably want this in the $\epsilon$ expansion regularization as talked below where a series $\sum_{n=1,\infty} n$ is regularized by introducing $\sum_{n=1,\infty} n e^{-\epsilon n}$

http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/08/06/the-abcd-of-divergent-series/

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but the number $a(n)$ of lattice points with norm $n$ is http://oeis.org/A046109. The answer would be something like $\frac{1}{4} \sum_n n a(n)$.

Comment: You could also try analytically continuing $\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty (m^2+n^2)^s$ where it converges to $s=1/2$.